# Some confusion about coordinate and quotient rings

Tags: ring-theory

I have some confusion about the properties regarding quotient rings. If we have a ring, $\frac{R}{I}$ then I understand that the quotient ring is the set of all equivalence classes $[f]$ such that $f$ is in $R$. I also understand that in this case, equivalence means that two elements, $x,y$ are equivalent if $x-y \in I$. But I don't quite understand what the set of all these equivalence classes means. Does this mean all sets of points in $R$ such that $x-y \in I$? Some concrete examples or other suggestions would be very helpful in understanding this, thank you.

Also, my confusion is specifically for when $R$ is a ring of polynomials.

Comment: I think it's helpful to write the equivalence class of an element $x\in R$ as $x+I$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? Where did you get that if $x \in R$ then that means $x + I$? thank you

Comment: The equivalence class of $x\in R$ is $x+I$.  A concrete example to think about (before you get to polynomials):  $R=\mathbb Z$ and $I=n\mathbb Z$